# Issue with Passing dockerbuildKit Secrets to Docker Using Devcontainer

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer, docker-buildkit, docker-secrets

I am experiencing a problem while attempting to pass a Personal Access Token (PAT) as a secret to Docker, utilizing the --secret flag in a devcontainer setup. I have configured the following lines in my devcontainer:

`"initializeCommand": "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 SECRET_TOKEN=$AZURE_ARTIFACT_TOKEN docker build --secret id=SECRET_TOKEN ."`
I have ensured that the $AZURE_ARTIFACT_TOKEN is present in my .bashrc file. Additionally, I have incorporated the secret in the Dockerfile as follows:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=SECRET_TOKEN \
 SECRET_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/SECRET_TOKEN) &&\
 echo $SECRET_TOKEN | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/***** &&\
 az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/*****/" --feed "thirdparty" --name "****" --version "0.2.1" --path ~/perception
```

Occasionally, the image is created successfully, and the Visual Studio Code configuring step is completed. However, there are instances where the dev containers step fails with the following error message:

> cat: /run/secrets/SECRET_TOKEN: No such file or directory

I attempted to resolve this issue by reinstalling Visual Studio Code, which temporarily fixed the problem. Unfortunately, the issue has resurfaced several times without any changes to the code.

**I want to emphasis the issue is only on devcontainer. when trying to run the initial command on terminal- the container is running properly**

what is the correct way to pass secrets to Docker using devcontainer? what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue:

I tried building via the terminal without `buildx`, and it succeeded. This led me to understand that the issue was with `buildx`.

When I ran `docker buildx ls` in the terminal, I saw that the `buildx` in use was the `docker-container` driver.

To fix the issue, **I changed it to use the default `buildx`** by running:

```bash
docker buildx use default
```

This resolved the problem.